Convergence of Mann Iterations
In https://arxiv.org/pdf/2309.03226, Theorem 2.6. states that certain iterations of self-mappings (maps with the same domain and codomain) converge to their fixed points when they're defined over complete metric spaces. However, I think the given citation is wrong (because the cited article works over uniformly convex Banach spaces). I never saw this result, and it seems to strong. In the literature the furthest I could track down were for continuous mappings on compact intervals over $R$. Basically I am looking for source for this theorem, as I could not find anything over metric spaces that resembles to anything like this. Any helps is appreciated.

Theorem 2.6. as stated in the cited paper is obviously wrong. If that were true it would imply that each function $f:X \to X$ (with no further properties) has a fixed point. By the way also Theorem 2.5 is wrong.

The statement in Theorem 2.6 is incorrect.
There are functions without fixed points whose Mann's iteration converges.
A classical exemple is the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $defined by $ f(x)=x+1$. The Mann's iteration is
$$
x_{n+1}=\alpha_{n}\cdot x_{n} + (1-\alpha_{n})\cdot f(x_{n})= x_{n}+\alpha_{n}
$$
Note that if the sequence $\{\alpha_{n}\}$ satisfies the weight conditions then $\{\alpha_{n}\}$ converges. Therefore, the Mann's iteration of $f$ converges.
